# cannot use a return statement in a function that uses observables

Tags: angular, asynchronous, return, angular2-observables

so I just learned that I cannot use a return statement in a function that uses a an async operation, or perhaps I can but I am using it incorrectly. My thought is that I should just subscribe to the obseravable in the place I want to use the data I am grabbing, instead of just calling the function in that place and using the return statement.

Here is my code what would be the better way of doing things so I don't have to use the return statement, or better yet, how can I still use the return statement. Please note I want to use observables, not promises, I no longer see the value in promises.

Thank you.

```
getService(url) {
    var value: any[] = [];
    this.http.get(url)
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          const data = response.json()
            .subscribe(
              (mappedData: any[]) => value = mappedData,
              (error) => console.log(error)
            )
              }
      );
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: getService() should return the value from the json object to the caller.. am i right ?

Comment: @mperle yes I am subscribed to the calling observer. Then as you can see in the subscribed part of the observable I set the variable value to the json response. Then I attempt to return that response in the function. But I was told that is a no go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding:

```
getService(url) {
  var value: any[] = [];                            // (1)
  this.http.get(url)                                // (2)
      .map(response => response.json() )            // (3)
      .subscribe(                                   // (4)
          mappedData => value = mappedData.data,    // (5)
          (error) => console.log(error)             // (6)
    );
    return value;                                   // (7)
}
```

When the `getService()` function is called ...

- Line 1 executes and sets value to an empty array.
- Line 2 executes, performing the Http get operation and setting up the Observable.
- Line 7 executes, returning the now still empty array.

AT SOME LATER POINT IN TIME, when the response is returned from the server ...

- Line 3 executes mapping the response to the JSON object and providing it to the subscribe method
- Line 5 executes, assigning the local value property to the data property of the mappedData and since the outer function already returned that property ... nothing is done with the resulting value.

This is the how I understand this code. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The doc referenced in the prior answer actually shows the code like this:

In an Angular service called `HeroService`:

```
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Notice that this is returning the Observable ... not a property. And that the calling code in the component includes the subscribe method:

In an Angular component called `HeroComponent`:

```
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getHeroes()
                   .subscribe(
                     heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Comment: so let me check my reference, but if we return the observeable the http call will not execute because it requires a subscription. Which makes me wonder if we can subscribe on the call in say a different component.

Comment: Yes. I'll enhance my answer to identify where the last two pieces of code reside.

Comment: ok this makes sense the only thing that kinda stinks is I cannot use one get method site wide as I will be returning a bunch of different types of get calls and cannot guarantee that I will be receving the expected data, instead of another services data, which is fine, it just means I have to create a bunch of different observables that are very similar. This is against dry, but... I am sure I can fix that with a comperator design patten. IDK still I think this answer of yours is the way to go!!!

Answer (score 0):

we can return the value of the json object this way.

```
getService(url) {
 var value: any[] = [];
 var subscription = this.http.get(url)
                    .map(response => response.json() )
                    .subscribe(
                         mappedData => value = mappedData.data,
                         (error) => console.log(error)
                    );
 return value;  }
```

1. transform the response from the `http.get()` to json object using `.map()`
2. then `.subscribe()` to the output of the .map() which is the transformed json object
3. Finally set the `value` from subscribed data.. return the value

Please go through the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) for better understanding.

Comment: so pretty much what I did with a few corrections. Which tells me the guy who yelled at me for doing it this way (litterally) is wrong. Looks like I get to have some fun at this expense thank you Homie!

Comment: How does this work? Isn't the returned value then always the empty array? This just does not seem right to me. Is it actually working?

Comment: i havent tried it to be honest it may not work I could try it but the time to set it up and test would be way to long for the time frame I am trying to acomplish @DeborahK how would you handle this?

Comment: @amazingCarrotSoup please check the edited answer this should work.

Comment: @mperle so your saying that we are able to hault execution and wait for the observable to return its values by setting a variable as an observable. It's interesting, I am going to test it

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't make a difference.

Comment: well what about this check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
getService(url) {
 var value: any[] = [];
 var subscription = this.http.get(url)
                    .map(response => response.json() )
    subscription.subscribe(
                 mappedData => value = mappedData.data,
                (error) => console.log(error)
                 );
                return value;  }
```

Comment: No. This is just a refactor of the above incorrect code. The value will still be empty. But I think your best bet is to try it. I have some operational code here all set up: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted All you'd have to do is change my getProducts method to any of the examples here to try these options.

Comment: i just tried your solution tested it and worked nicely. I have to change the architecture of my site a bit but thats ok. Your solution is great. Thanks dude I will take a look at your code on github too, I appreciate you going through all the trouble